# word for "turn to lowercase"

Tags: vocabulary, capitalization

What word is used to signify "change/transform letters from uppercase to lowercase?" Uncapitalize? Decapitalize? The grammar check on my laptop suggests these words are not commonly used, or they do not exist.

Thanks

Comment: A number of computer languages use 'downcase' as the name of a function or method for doing this (eg https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase).  But are you looking for a more general term that non-programmers would understand?

Comment: 'Downcase' seems sufficient, but if there is a more generally-used term, I'd like to know of that, too! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use [lowercase as a verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lowercase):

> transitive verb
>   : to print or set in lowercase letters

I think that would encompass changing existing text to lower case. Googling for "lowercase the text" brings up "About 26,900 results" some of which, at least, seem to have that meaning.

Comment: Google search gives wildly inaccurate numbers as estimates. The actual number of hits is closer to 43.

Comment: @Laurel At least with that number I can check that most of them do, indeed, correspond to this use!

Answer (score 2):

I've always used (and heard used) ***upshift*** and ***downshift*** to describe the act of changing case, but I don't see it in any dictionaries.  Perhaps it is an *old computer dude* thing (been in the business nearly 40 years now).  Here are some examples, however:

From the [HP3000 Edit Manual](http://www.3kranger.com/HP3000/mpeix/doc3k/B3031690001.11625/92.htm):

> **Downshift Character**
>
> *Purpose*
> Converts one or more alphabetic characters to lowercase.

As an old HP3k guy, this may very well be where I first learned it.  Also, note that there are related commands to *downshift* a word and an entire line, as well as the *upshift* equivalents.

From the [Multi-Edit forums](http://multieditsoftware.com/forums/topic/changing-case-of-keywords/):

> *Your macro would examine the word prior to the space (allowing for leading/trailing punctuation) and, if it is a keyword, would **upshift** or **downshift** it.*

From the book [Nook for Dummies](https://books.google.com/books?id=p43I8LPBhZUC&pg=PT45&lpg=PT45&dq=%22downshift%22%20lowercase%20uppercase&source=bl&ots=DEPBQkw9w8&sig=GBawXiMltBvIMGfT6lAmDXPpvkI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirree-ksjcAhWKhVQKHZKsCSMQ6AEwBnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22downshift%22%20lowercase%20uppercase&f=false):

> *To lock the upper case keyboard so that it doesn't **downshift** to lowercase...*

And lastly, editor Taylor Sperry at the publisher Melville House [discusses](https://www.mhpbooks.com/theres-no-i-in-internet/) the New York Times, Associated Press, and Wall Street Journal all switching to a lowercase *I* in the word *internet*:

> But this *downshift* from uppercase-I to lowercase-i “internet” suggests something more than an aesthetic accommodation.

Hope this helps.